# How do i write function for clicking on particular cell in ng2-smart-table(Not row click)..?

Tags: angular6

I have tried with below code but not working for me in ng2-smart-tale settings

```
settings = {
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID'
      },
      name: {
        title: 'Full Name',
        type: 'html',
        valuePrepareFunction: (OrderId) => {
          return  '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:onCustom()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>'+OrderId+'</a>'; 
        }
      },
      username: {
        title: 'User Name'
      },
      email: {
        title: 'Email'
      }
    }
  };
```

Please suggest me how to add click function when we click on particular cell (not row select)

Comment: I dont know this Table.
but I dont understand why are you using "onclick" in Angular.
It might be the reason why you fail.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example for you. It uses row data to format a custom component. But if you wish, you can use cell data. To do that change row with cell like that: **valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => cell**. After that you should modify your custom component (MyNameComponent). But if you don't modify the whole example and use it as-is, it should work.

```
name: {
  title: 'Name',
  type: 'custom',
  valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => row,
  renderComponent: MyNameComponent
}
```

MyNameComponent

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-name-component',
  template: `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:onCustom()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>{{name}}</a>`
})
export class MyNameComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() value;
  name;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.name = this.value.name
  }    
}
```